# How do I round up on a TI-84+

Tags: calculator, ti-83

I'm using a TI-84+ and am trying to setup an equation that requires rounding up

I know how to round and round down with the TI-84 but I can't seem to figure out how to round up

Edit: the 'round down' function I mentioned isn't truly round down it's 'ipart' which gives you the integer portion of the number which for positive numbers does round down but for negative numbers rounds up which negates the suggestion of negate the number then round down then negate again

Comment: Thanks for your question, but this calculator is relatively recent (introduced 2004) and is still in production. Thus, it doesn't qualify as [on-topic](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site. You might try [math.se]; they have [a number of questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=ti+calculator) (albeit more sophisticated than this one) related to doing things on modern TI calculators.

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson LOL I already asked over at Mathematics and I was told it was off topic for over there and was suggested here or stackoverflow

Comment: Ah! Sorry about misdirecting you, then. I'm not too familiar with [math.se] and, though I looked through their help pages, I didn't see anything mentioning calculators at all, so I just went by a quick search for TI-84 questions. (As you can see, it's good to check the help pages for what's on topic before posting in a new SE since redirects from others may be wrong.)

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson Frankly I'm of the opinion that I asked in the right place the first time but it's such a niche issue that they don't really want to deal with it and are trying to pass the buck as it were but here's the link I was given https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324762/where-should-i-ask-questions-about-using-ti-84-calculators

Comment: Ah, thanks for that link. I've pointed out to the person who suggested RC that the calculator is still being manufactured and supported, and is part of TI's current lineup. Given that he quoted our remit as, "How to use or preserve computing equipment that is no longer manufactured or supported by the manufacturer" in his answer, I can only think that he must have thought this was an obsolete calculator, not a current one.

Comment: Is there room for a bit of linguistic naziism? If so: negate means *nullify*. If you negate a number, you set it to 0. You probably considered *negativing*, not *negating* (no matter how stupid it sounds).

Comment: Is there room for lingustic freedom fighters? As a software developer, I have long understood "negate" to mean what the unary `-` operator in some high-level languages does, what the op-code `NEG` in some assembly languages does, what the `CHS` key on a classic HP calculator does. That is, I've always understood it to mean, "compute the additive inverse of a given number." I never even knew, until I looked it up just now, that you could use "negative" as a verb.

Answer (score 6):

Aside from the `ipart` function that you mention, there is also `int` which, according to the manual, returns the largest integer smaller equal to the input, i.e. it truly rounds down.
You can use this to round *up* with the expression `-int(-x)`.

Answer (score 1):

Add one and then round down. But make sure the number is not *already* an integer, because adding 1 and then rounding down would end up adding 1.

Comment: indeed but the issue is I'm trying to stick this in the middle of a formula and I won't know if it's an integer or not ahead of time

Comment: I'm sure that calculator will have some way of doing conditional comparisons. I'm not familiar with that specific model so I can't suggest a specific procedure.